# PyQGIS: standard and advanced linear referencing possibilities

Tags: pyqgis, linear-referencing, qgis-2.6

I'm aware of the existence of the following QGIS plugins:

1. [QChainage](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/)
2. [Event layer](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/event_layer/)
3. [linear referencing](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/linear_ref/)
4. [LRS](http://blazek.github.io/lrs/release/help.0.3.5/index.html)

Although, all of these tools offer some linear referencing capabilities, I find that they lack in terms of their ability to be used directly from a standalone python script, are not part of the base QGIS platform, and are not on par with LRS capabilities found in other GIS software. Some of these features include but are not limited to:

1. **Locate features along a road:** The ability to extract events from a vector layer into a data table (ex: CSV) of some sort
2. **Overlay events:** Take two different event tables (non GIS) that share the same `road_id` and combine/merge/split/etc them automatically
3. **Make route event layer:** combine an existing road layer with a new event table with added bonus to do `right` vs. `left` buffer if negative numbers are present.

**My question:**

What are my options to perform advanced linear referencing using Python QGIS?

Comment: You don't need the plugins, use `point= line.interpolate(distance)` (based on [Generating chainage (distance) nodes in QGIS](http://nathanw.net/2012/08/05/generating-chainage-distance-nodes-in-qgis/))